# BluetoothAdapter: getState() : mService = null. Returning STATE_OFF repeats infinitely

Tags: android, bluetooth, logcat, android-bluetooth

I keep getting this in my logcat, repeatedly, if I choose `No Filter`. Having trouble tracing down the application that is causing this. Anyone have an idea of what is causing this? I wonder if it has anything to do with the Wear App.

[image]

Comment: I'm also seeing it and I also run the Wear app, and see it even when my own BLE app isn't installed.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's the Wear app. I just uninstalled it and reinstalled it to check.

Answer (score 0):

The logging stops when you uncheck the setting "Debugging over Bluetooth" inside your Android Wear Companion App. You don't have to uninstall the app.